# Django sslserver (https) is getting slow gradually

Tags: python, django, ssl, django-sslify

I installed secure connection to django server with the help of django ssl server. It was working properly with minimum margin speed between http and https connection. Gradually after adding code more and more day by day, I could see the https connection is very slow.

Can you please help me out to make it resolved?

`python /root/celestial_NAS/manage.py runsslserver --certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt --key /etc/ssl/private/server.key --addrport 0.0.0.0:443 &`

And also give me some cautions/tips to maintain optimums performance for https with django server.(used django sslserver API )

Thanks,
NagaPavan

Comment: Out of interest why are you not either serving this via a reverse proxy terminating SSL -- something like nginx/Apache, and why you aren't running your django app with a WSGI server

Comment: @jvc26, Hi I am using WSGI server as I defined WSGI_APPLICATION = 'celestial_NAS.wsgi.application' in settings.py and run the sslserver with manage.py. Can you please suggest me what might be the reason for the issue with performance of https but not http...https loading very slow then it is getting crashed some times.